# Entropy of 2 interacting states vs 1 combined state

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, probability

Suppose I have 2 Einstein solids, $A$ and $B$, which have $N_A$ and $N_B$ oscillators, are weakly coupled and have $q_{tot}$ units of energy distributed between them.

**Why is the multiplicity (and thus the entropy) of a combined $A$ and $B$** ($N_A + N_B$) **greater than the multiplicity of the most likely state of a weakly coupled $A$ and $B$?** (a proportionately distributed $q_A$ and $q_B$)

I'm looking for a conceptual/intuitive explanation here.

More generally, **is the multiplicity of two containers always greater when considered as one giant container?**

**Will the answer to the aforementioned questions change if the volume (or $N_A$ and $N_B$) are the same ($N_A = N_B$)?**

The inspiration for the question comes from problem 2.29 of "Thermal Physics" by Schroeder. The question doesn't ask this exactly but its solution can be found [here](https://physicspages.com/pdf/Schroeder/Schroeder%20Problems%2002.28-30.pdf) (scroll down to "Example 2"):

Comment: That system does not correctly give the entropy of an Einstein solid (which is collection of identical, distinguishable harmonic oscillators).

Comment: I'm confused... if they are identical then they are indistinguishable (as a consequence of quantum mechanics). No?

Comment: No, because they are located at different fixed positions.  They are identical in the sense that they are simple harmonic oscillators, all with the same frequency, but each one is at a specific lattice site.  They are not like particles that can move and are indistinguishable under exchange.

Regardless, that is unrelated to what is wrong with that link's description, which looks like it is probably describing a collection of identical, indistinguishable two-level systems.

Comment: Got it. That makes sense. Regardless, I'm not sure what you see is wrong with the link's description. Anyhow, I'm still wondering about my original question(s)